SOAP Office.js EWS ReplyView getAttachments
I want to generate a SOAP request to download the attachments of the email I am replying to (so I am in a MessageComposeCommandSurface, not in MessageReadCommandSurface, I know there would be an API for MessageReadCommandSurface to use - but the view in question is a MessageComposeCommandSurface :().
So I am trying to implement something what is proposed in the answer here (but no code was provided there): How can I get the message above that I am replying to in outlook addin using office js?
So far, I have come up with the following SOAP Request:
The conversationID is set via: const conversationID = Office.context.mailbox.item!.conversationId;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <FindItem  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                 xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
                 Traversal="Shallow">
        <ItemShape>
          <t:BaseShape>AllProperties</t:BaseShape>
        </ItemShape>

        <Restriction>
          <IsEqualTo>
            <FieldURI FieldURI="item:ConversationId" />
            
            <FieldURIOrConstant>
              <Constant Value="${conversationID.value}" />
            </FieldURIOrConstant>
          </IsEqualTo>
        </Restriction>

        <ParentFolderIds>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>
          <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="outbox"/>
        </ParentFolderIds>
      </FindItem >
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>

But somehow, this approach returns everything currently in the Inbox, a behaviour that I cannot understand at all.

In EWS you would be better using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaginreplytoid-canonical-property extended property to get the InternetMessageId of the message your replying to (from the draft message in compose) then do a search based on that value.

Thank you for your answear, but we are developing an office.js adding using TypeScript, so the C API is of little use to us.

The link just give the property definition that can be include in the SOAP query to EWS eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420551/extended-property-in-ews
